# jquery remove() function causes jumping to the top of the page

Tags: jquery

```
$("#txt_catId").change(function(){

    var catId = $('#txt_catId').val();

    $(".news-row").remove();
    $("#txt_news_id").remove();

    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'urlExample',
          data : {cat_id : catId},
          success: function(data) {
            $('#txt_catId').parent().append(data);
          },

          statusCode: {
            404: function() {
              alert("page not found");
            }
          }


        });

});
```

What this code does is: when a user choose a category, a list of news of that category will appear as a selectbox. But the point is every time I choose a category, it always jumps to the top of the page. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: please set up a fiddle example :) Also post your markup

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using a link with `href="#"` as means of choosing a category. Activating the link will take you to the top of the page, as that's what the empty bookmark means.

Use `preventDefault` in the event handler to stop the link from being activated:

```
$("#txt_catId").change(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning about it, #txt_catId is not a link, it's a dropdown list(<select></select>)